# Docker build failing with error at array-slice

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install

I'm running a docker build in windows and npm has failed in a step called array-slice. I installed the dependency manually and re-ran the build. Then it failed on buffer-from.

It says it cannot access the dependency url in the error - but it works when I test it in the browser - which seems to me that my docker build process is having trouble to access some urls, for some reason...

```
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/array-unique/-/array-unique-0.3.2.tgz
```

Is there any necessary additional config to make sure npm can access those dependencies?

This is my Dockerfile content:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3333

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just an installation issue on windows... Removed everything, including virtualbox, and installed it all again... seems to work fine now...

The only problem is that my app is still not exposed to the port I've requested... but that's another question.